# Android Library To Facilitate A Layout Builder App?

Tags: android, java

I was wondering if there was some sort of library (Java) that could help me make my own layout builder app. For example, take a look at Eventbrite:

[image: Eventbrite application]

This is the direction where I want to go and would like to accomplish.